# Missing Javascript Intellisense inside cshtml for Telerik UI Asp.net MVC (Kendo)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am very new to web development. Currently I'm working with Javascript + Kendo UI ASP.net mvc

I downloaded one of the sample project of telerik about using Autocomplete column inside telerik UI Grid MVC. However, i can't see any Javascript Instellisense support inside the  tag in the file View/Index.cshtml.

I have searched for few days and still couldn't find a solution. Follow this link and doesn't work for me 
[Kendo Javascript Intellisense](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/vs-intellisense)

It is really hard to learn/understand/apply code now because there is no javascript intellisense.

Can someone help me how to make javascript intellisense work with this Sample Project [My SampleProject Link](https://github.com/jakieHuynh/No-Intellisense-Javascript) . You can check the included Picture in the GitHub to know the part not show Javascript Intellisense (View/Index.cshtml)
Note: I can see Jquery Intellisense.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Justcode from Telerik will do the trick.
http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/javascript-support.aspx

Use the trial version to test it.